# Desktop organizer using python using glob, os, shutil and tkinter

Tags: python, macos, tkinter, operating-system, desktop-application

I made this desktop organizer that takes files that are the same type and puts them into a folder, but now it only moves 1 file to the folder, and I would like to move it all.

Code:

```
import glob, os
import shutil
import tkinter as tk

def png():
    os.chdir("/Users/19379/Desktop")
    for file in glob.glob("*.png"):
            print(file)
            os.makedirs("PNG Pictures")
            shutil.move(file,"PNG Pictures")


def mp3():
    os.chdir("/Users/19379/Desktop")
    for file in glob.glob("*.mp3"):
        print(file)
        os.makedirs("mp3 ")
        shutil.move(file,"mp3")

def jpeg():
    os.chdir("/Users/19379/Desktop")
    for file in glob.glob("*.jpg"):
        print(file)
        os.makedirs("jpeg")
        shutil.move(file,"jpeg")

def mp4():
    os.chdir("/Users/19379/Desktop")
    for file in glob.glob("*.mp4"):
        print(file)
        os.makedirs("mp4 ")
        shutil.move(file,"mp4")

root = tk.Tk()
frame = tk.Frame(root)
frame.pack()

png1 = tk.Button(frame,
                    text="PNG",
                    fg="red",
                    command=png)
png1.pack(side=tk.LEFT)

mp31 = tk.Button(frame,
                    text="MP3",
                    fg="red",
                    command=mp3)
mp31.pack(side=tk.LEFT)

jpeg1 = tk.Button(frame,
                    text="JPEG",
                    fg="red",
                    command=jpeg)
jpeg1.pack(side=tk.LEFT)

mp41 = tk.Button(frame,
                    text="MP4",
                    fg="red",
                    command=mp4)
mp41.pack(side=tk.LEFT)

root.mainloop()
```

Comment: ` os.makedirs("PNG Pictures")` shouldn't be in a for-loop. I guess you want the folder just once?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are making dirs in a loop without needing them to be made in a loop (It can't create two folders in the same path with the same names). What I suggest you do is either move the line to before the loop, or make the folders before running, since you'll want your files in the same folders anyway.
It is probably causing an error that pauses the process and that's why it only moves one file.